# If my disc is beyond repair, can I buy the game on XBox Live without losing my saves?

Tags: xbox-360, fable-2

I had a copy of Fable 2, but it keeps crashing at the same place all the time. I tried to install it, but it won't work and the only options I have left is to either buy a new disc or buy it on XBox Live. I would rather not leave my house so I'm wondering, will I lose my saves if I buy it online?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Your game saves are tied to the console's hard drive itself. You can use either disk or digital to play the game and your save will be intact.

[information about storage (see supported content)](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/storage)

Comment: That said, you can buy it for a fraction of the digital price if you simply buy it used. I'd recommend a place like Best Buy (if in the U.S.), where they currently have the pre-owned copy listed at $5.

Comment: Go rent a copy or borrow one, you can copy it to the HDD then.